# How Would Mathematics and Technology evolve in a world where people can teleport

Tags: technology, science-in-society, mathematics, teleportation

I've already talked about this world in this [How would criminals be punished in a world where everyone can teleport?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/203394/how-would-criminals-be-punished-in-a-world-where-everyone-can-teleport)

> Everyone in this world from the age of 5 can teleport to anywhere they have been before even if they forgot how to go there. This started about 4,000 B.C.E where a bright green star landed on earth and affected all humans to be able to teleport, they can teleport with them 5 times their weight (they choose what they bring) and if anyone forgets a place they've been they can not go there. The reason why young people can't teleport is because the part of the brain isn't fully developed.

My story takes place between 3,000 B.C.E and 2,000 B.C.E. I want to know how advance would they be by then?

I thought of a quick way to measure the distance of planets, the moon and the sun. If a person wanted to measure how far the moon is approximately all they need to do is walk 40 or so miles and then check the angle of the moon in both spots. I also thought that moving things would be easer so building big structures like the pyramids would take less time.

Comment: Can a group of people in concert teleport larger objects than they can move individually?

Comment: @DWKraus probably If they have all been to said place they could.

Comment: The fact that everyone can teleport easily and heavily affects war strategies, information sharing and relaying, espionage related issues, transportation technology regarding small cargo and the like, all of which can and most likely would impact how technology develops. This question sounds a bit too big to be properly answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Information flow will be much faster**

As pointed out quite a few experiments will be much easier to conduct, but I think the more important is the speedup of the flow of information and ideas.

Before the internet and modern society information flow was slow. Scientists had to converse slowly by letter if they conversed at all. This leads to slow progress and things being invented multiple times over the course of hundreds of years. Take as an example the printing press.

With teleportation you basically have a human internet where the scientific community can very easily share information. Also inventors, engineers and entrepreneurs would very quickly use information for the development of new tools and machines.

I think you will basically immediately see an increase in scientific development we have seen from the start of the industrial revolution but even faster.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematics and science would accelerate very fast after everything cooled down from the sudden confusion. If someone has a question about let’s say gravity “ do heavier objects fall faster than light objects” they could test it in a few seconds teleporting a bolder about twice their weight and a big rock on top of a cliff and then teleporting to the bottom. A lot of experiments would be easy to test. This would accelerate technology as well.

Comment: You didn’t mention how building tall structures like the pyramids. you can carry the heavy blocks using teleportation.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this is it will be accelerating faster and faster, everyone will be able to teleport anywhere (they could possibly go) so testing things like gravity, speed of sound and later maybe the speed of light would be easy. Because things would be lighter through teleporting things can be built about 6 times as fast and $\frac{1}{6}$ times the cost. so building and other things would be cheaper. life would also be peaceful and good.